# javascript change text to element's alt text on hover

Tags: javascript, html, alt

I've got a series of images, and, upon hover, I'd like them to change the text of a `<span>` element. I accomplished this before with some very redundant javascript, changing the text of the `<span>` on every onMouseIn and onMouseOut for every image, each with a unique ID. I used this code, repeated several times:

```
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById("foo").onmouseover = function () {
    document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = "bar";
};

document.getElementById("foo").onmouseout = function () {
    document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = "bar";
};
```

But I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, using the `alt` tag of the image. On image hover, I'd want the `<span>` tag to display the hovered image's `alt` text, and onMouseOut, go back to normal. How would this be done? Thanks.

Comment: can you add a fiddle for what you want ?

Comment: You can access the *alt* text of an image by doing `element.alt`, so `this.alt` in your case. Also you could use a class with `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events other than many id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get all elements in the page using tag name as below and add the event handlers

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    span = document.getElementById("element");
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
      span.innerHTML = this.alt || '';
    });
    imgs[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      span.innerHTML = '';
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="element"></span>
<br />
<img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=1" alt="img 1" />
<img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=2" alt="img 2" />
<img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=3" alt="img 3" />
<img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=4" alt="img 4" />
```

If you don't want to target all the img element, then you can add a class to all the images which need to trigger it, then use `document.getElementsByClassName('classname')` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('img')`

Comment: Instead of *getElementsByTagName* there is also *document.images*. ;-)